# How to prevent water temperature and pH sensor corrosion in salt water

Tags: sensor, monitor, waterproof, underwater

I am going to design an salt water monitoring system. Salt water will cause sensors to rust very fast.
Any suggestion on how to prevent it?
Any temperature and pH sensor suggest to use in the system?

Comment: There are sensors specifically designed for salt water. That would be my choice.

Comment: I’m pretty sure there are glass body pH probes.

Comment: calibrate two sensors, then test one in a thin silicon bag...

Comment: Make them out of things that don't corrode in salt water. Try glass, platinum and/or gold.

Comment: How much is your time worth?  There's industrial sensors designed to work in all kinds of harsh environments.  Just search out a company that sells them, and deplete your bank account.  Temperature is easy -- just encase the probe in stainless steel.  A pH sensor actually has to interact chemically with its environment, so more $$$ will be involved in making one that'll hold up.